# Convert to inHomogeneous cordinates Eigen::MatrixXf

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I have a 3x1000 matrix `Eigen::MatrixXf`. I need to divide the matrix with the 3rd row.

```
A(0,:) = A(0,:) / A(2,:)
A(1,:) = A(1,:) / A(2,:)
A(2,:) = A(2,:) / A(2,:)
```

How can I perform this operation in Eigen. In particular I cannot find anything for componentwise division

Answer (score 0):

Use as an array:

```
A.array() /= A.array().col(2);
```

For more information, see the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialArrayClass.html#TutorialArrayClassConvert).